# How to have standalone installer for my vue application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want my application to be downloaded and Installation should happen even without any internet access after downloading.
So i need standalone installer. How to implement this?

Comment: From where do you want to download the vue js application?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is intended to be an offline capable web application you'll want to set up a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker) and cache as much of your application as possible. There are a few other requirements which are detailed in [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners) which will allow browsers to display an install banner for your application so users can add it to their homescreen/desktop.

If you just want to distribute your application as a desktop application such as the slack/discord applications then you will need to package your project as an [electron app](https://electronjs.org/). This will create an executable which acts like any other program you install to your computer.

If you require any further information I would suggest asking a more specific question detailing exactly what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far.